# how to call a variable from one php function into another php function in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pdo

```
 <?php
 $host = 'localhost';
 $dbname   = 'project';
$username = 'root';
$password = '1234';
$charset = 'utf8';


  try {
 $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

 $sql = 'SELECT subject,description,time,date FROM status ORDER BY time DESC';


$q = $pdo->query($sql);

$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $usid = ($row['userID']);
 $sql1 = 'SELECT status.subject, status.description, status.time , status.date , status.stno , status.userID , tbl_users.userID , tbl_users.Fname , tbl_users.Lname 
  FROM status , tbl_users WHERE status.userID=tbl_users.userID ORDER BY status.time DESC';



 $q1 = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
$q1->execute([$usid]);
$q1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
}

 ?>
```

This is my code and using PDO i am calling some variable in my html file for example

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row1['Fname']); ?>&nbsp;<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row1['Lname']); ?>
```

and now I want to add another php script within the same page and need **Lname** which is a name of a column in mysql to be there in another php script of the same page but i don't know how do i call it their , please help me

Comment: Quick and dirty way is to declare the variable as `global`

Comment: @Jeff can please tell me the code that i can put in my first script and the calling code in my second script so it could help me , please...

Comment: This is too vague. You are speaking of functions, but I don't see any functions in your code. I'm quite confused and don't know how to answer because I'm unsure of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you mean by "I want to add another php script within the same page".

However, if you use `require_once 'file';` or `include 'file'` AFTER you've declared the $Lname variable, it will automatically inherit all the variables that have been declared *before the include*

So, like this:

**PHP file 1:**

```
<?php
  $variable = "I'm a variable";
  //some script here
  require_once 'my2ndscript.php';
  $wrongVariable = "this will not be inherited by my2ndscript.php";
?>
```

**PHP file 2, my2ndscript.php:**

```
<?php
  echo $variable;
  echo $wrongVariable;
?>
```

Result will be "I'm a variable" with a warning that "wrongVariable is not defined"

If you really are speaking of functions and not lose scripts, you could use the "global" variable as a sloppy way. However, this is not recommended and won't be appreciated by many people. like so:

```
<?php 
  $variable = "foo";

  function renderFoo(){
    global $foo; //foo is now available because you said you want to inherit it.
    echo $foo;
  }

  renderFoo();
?>
```

Another way is to add arguments. You can pass arguments to any function like so:

```
  $variable = "foo";

  function renderFoo($Lname){
    echo $Lname; //is automatically available as the argument
  }

renderFoo($variable);
```

Comment: both files are on one page , how can i use include or require once ?

Comment: What do you mean both files are on one page?

It's simply `include 'pathToYourFile.php';`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword for beginner level non object oriented design.

Without any example of what you're working with, I'm guessing you would like to try something like this

```
<?php
 $host = 'localhost';
 $dbname   = 'project';
 $username = 'root';
 $password = '1234';
 $charset = 'utf8';

 global $row;

 // code as normal


function example(){
   global $row;
   // now you have access to $row
}
```